# Displaying Attachments (pdf/jpeg) in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser

I am trying to display some attachments inline in a popup using window.open().

I am using object tag to display data. But everytime i see a grey screen in IE. This works fine in other browsers like firefox, chrome etc

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: The way I've done this is from the server side and changing the header information to tell the browser how to display the data.  You can't do this from the server?

Comment: show me code that you tried so that i can help you?

Comment: I am using the following code <object data="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PW0000000GudBMAS" height="500" id="attach" type="application/pdf" width="100%" />
                                    
                                </embed>